# The getter 'doc' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot<Object>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a food track app with bar scanning and I'm working with firebase_auth 3.3.12 and firestore. My code in the database.dart is:

```
List<Scan> _scanListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return snapshot.doc.map((doc){
    return Scan(
      productID: doc.documentID,
      productName: doc.data['food_name'] ?? '',
      productCalories: doc.data['calories'] ?? 0,
      productCarbs: doc.data['carbohydrates'] ?? 0,
      productFat: doc.data['fat'] ?? 0,
      productProtein: doc.data['protein'] ?? 0,
      dateTime: doc.data['date_time'] ?? null,
      grams: doc.data['amount_had'] ?? 0,
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

I get the error:

> The getter 'doc' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'

What 's wrong?

Comment: It's `docs` and not `doc`

Answer (score 1):

Posting @Dharmaraj comment for better visibility:

You used `doc` instead of `docs`. Correct line:

```
 return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
```

Answer (score 0):

You migh need call `docs` not `doc`. Remember `QuerySnapshot` -> `DocumentSnapshot` -> `Your Item`